# search in subdirectories for all html files containing the tag <abbr>

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a directory include many files of different extensions. What I want is to list all `.html` files only that contains the tag .

Answer (score 5):

From the terminal, use the `find` command to find all the files ending in .html and use the `grep` command to filter the results to show only the names of files that contain the `<abbr>` string:

```
cd /path-to-dir ## change directories to the root directory that you are searching from
find . -name "*.html" -exec grep -l '<abbr>' {} +
```

The `find` command searches for files in a directory hierarchy recursively by default.

Or combine the two commands into a single command:

```
find /path-to-dir -name "*.html" -exec grep -l '<abbr>' {} +
```

Comment: +1 but why `cd /path-to-dir` and not just `find /path-to-dir`? That seems to be adding needless complexity. I would also use `-exec ... +` instead of `-exec \;` to improve efficiency.

Comment: You shouldn't search for `<abbr>` but for `<abbr`, since a tag may have attributes and won't be matched with `<abbr>`.

Comment: @karel Isn't that what I just said?

Comment: Still `grep -r` simpler than `find` then `exec grep`. Take a look on my answer

Comment: That's one thing I did in order to make my bash transparent and self-explanatory. The other thing I did was that I didn't add [regex for matching open HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) which could be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
grep -r "<abbr" --include="*.html" /path-to-dir
```

- use `-r` for all subdirectories.
- Use `--include='*html'` to match html files only.

Answer (score 0):

For verification (namely, the `file name` and the `lines with <abbr>`), you may use a simple:

```
grep '<abbr>' /path-to-dir/*.html
```

If you want *file names* only, use the following:

```
grep '<abbr>' /path-to-dir/*.html | awk -F: '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq
```